# Add a specific layout for a subfolder controller

Tags: controller, sails.js

I have an admin subfolder in my controllers folder and i want to set a specific layout for all the view of this folder.

I have already tryed something like this with routes config :

```
 '/admin/*': {
    locals: {
      layout: 'dashboard'
    }
  },
```

But it's doesn't work. Thanks for your help.

Edit :
For the moment i use a policy which match with the request url.

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    var re = /^admin\//;
    var matchUrl = re.exec(req.options.controller);

    if (!_.isNull(matchUrl)) {
        res.locals.layout = 'dashboard';
    }

    return next();
};
```

Comment: Is there another way to achieve this, without the policy workaround ?